# LESS selector with sub-class parent

Tags: css, less

How can I affect child of specified parent sub-class selector?
I making my class names in camel case, so I build my LESS file like this:

```css
.popup {
    &Content {
        &Title {
            opacity: 0;
        }
    }
    &.active {
        &Content {
            &Title {
                opacity: 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But it does not exactly what I need. It compiles to

```css
.popupContentTitle {
    opacity: 0;
}
.popup.activeContentTitle
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Is there way to compile it properly:

```css
.popupContentTitle {
    opacity: 0;
}
.popup.active .popupContentTitle
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by appending the ampersand after the nested selector:

```
.popup {
    &Content {
        &Title {
            opacity: 0;

            .popup.active & {
               opacity:1;  
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this the only way? Because I'm using this method and it's can make it kinda dirty when ".active" is not class for root element.

Comment: @ApocaliptynBane Personally I find the reuse of "popup" as part of a class name concatenation, as well as a class on it's own quite complicated. This is the cleanest way I can think of achieving the result you are after.

Comment: Thank you for your time. Sadly I'm not get better solution, that I had before asking. Perhaps this is the only way.

Answer (score 0):

See [`parent selectors order`](http://lesscss.org/features/#parent-selectors-feature-changing-selector-order).
E.g.:

```css
.popup {
    &Content {
        &Title {
            opacity: 0;
            .popup.active & { 
                opacity: 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And please don't overnest - there's no point in splitting `.popupContentTitle` into three separate blocks if it's actually the one with the only set of properties. I.e. it should really be just:

```css
.popupContentTitle {
    opacity: 0;
    .popup.active & { 
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

And finally the often question: do you really have any `.active .popupContentTitle` element which is NOT a `.popup.active .popupContentTitle`? I.e. the first `.popup` there is most likely redundand.

Comment: This is just example of structure. Of course there will be some styles for .popup and .popupContent separately. Witch means this nesting is justified.